# Allowing only "Eligible/Allowed" users to install apk app

Tags: android, installation, android-permissions

I want to make my Android application such that only eligible/allowed users can install or use it. 
Like: to set device IMEI of allowed devices in manifest. Or something/anything like this? Or to ask for a device's specific code which should be entered to use the application?

Comment: There is nothing you can do to prevent a User to download your app from play store. No checks as such can be implemented. However you can implement these checks once the app is installed and block the app flow for a certain case. You can also trigger a self unInstall process on your app. But only after it has been downloaded.

Comment: Ok. Its Ok that app can be downloaded and installed. But can I make the app such that if the device is not registered or eligible then the app simply don't run. Simply a toast: "You are not allowed to use this app" or something like this??? Or if it's not possible can a "key generator" works ??? Like keygen is another apk app but both the app and keygen have "mutually understanding" such that the key generated by keygen "works with the app". (OFFLINE) ????

Comment: "works with the app"==========> This requires ContentResolver. You see, Contacts is an app that can share its data with any other app using ContentResolver. Same way you can make to apps to share data between them using ContentResolver and ContentProviders.